# Declare value ONCE to use in multiple controller methods - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I currently have to declare my Stripe api key in every controller method that will make an api call to Stripe. For example

```
public function __construct()
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
}

public function addCard()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
}

public function updateCard()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
}

public function deleteCard()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
}
```

This is getting very annoying as I have more than 10 methods that are doing this. My question is, is there a way i can declare the key somewhere ONCE and not have to call it in every controller method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, I'd do it in your `AppServiceProvider`. You'll find this at `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.

Stick it in the register method:

```
public function register()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
}
```

That will run during bootstrap for every request.

---

Alternatively you could set this in the constructor for your Controller. This would cause it to run for all actions in this one controller only.

```
class PaymentController extends Controller { 

    public function __construct() {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_KEY'));
    }

    public function addCard() {
        ...
```

I'd argue this is less desirable, your service providers should primarily be responsible for wiring up your dependencies. Up to you.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. By 'every request' do you mean that it will also run when some other controller method in a different controller is called? Say MyController@myMethod?

Comment: Yep. It'll run as part of the global bootstrap process. If you're worried about this being wasteful, don't be. If you look at the [Stripe class](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe.php#L40) it's literally just storing the api key in a variable. Utterly harmless to do this on every request, and convenient to just have it ready whenever you want it.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a way to limit it to 1 controller? Sorry, Im new to Laravel and havent really explored what it has to offer.

Comment: @ArvinFlores I just updated my answer with that alternative

Comment: I like the servicecontainer answer too, it just bugs me for some reason that it will run for every request. Just tried the edited answer but got the Stripe server error for No API key provided.

Comment: @ArvinFlores Double check the name of that constructor. Two underscores. `__construct()`. Stick a `dd` in there to make sure it's getting called. This will work for you.

Comment: returns null with the dd. I will try to figure this out. +1 for helpfulness

Comment: What returns null? You're missing something quite simple. Feel free to update your question and show your controller class (with the constructor) if you'd like me to look at it.